# Generating Random SubLink In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to know how I could generate a random sublink such as if I have a website called hello.com and I want to be able to let a user have their own part of the webpage such as hello.com/123. I would like to make it in JavaScript.

Please help and I would like to not use Scaledrone's API.

Thank you

Comment: Would you like to generate a random string / numbers / both?

Comment: Yes please. That would be helpful